# Why can't I find the Witcher 3 Collectors Edition for preorder?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I'm an avid Witcher fan and would like to preorder the collector's edition of the game. Unfortunately, all places ([Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00KSN7OGC), [Gamestop](http://www.gamestop.com/xbox-one/games/the-witcher-iii-wild-hunt-collectors-edition/115386), [BestBuy](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/the-witcher-wild-hunt-collectors-edition-xbox-one/7282017.p?id=1219262399206&skuId=7282017)) that seem to offer the collectors edition say it is unavailable. I found a [post](http://forums.bestbuy.com/t5/Let-s-Talk-Games/The-Witcher-3-Collector-s-Edition-Pre-order/td-p/822026) from a BestBuy employee stating the game is unavailable.

My question is this: Am I stuck with having to preorder a less equiped item like [this](http://amzn.com/B00FUC6SZO)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, most everywhere is sold out. Pre-orders for this horribly gaudy and wonderful collector's edition went up quite a while ago, and I snagged mine back then (according to Amazon, my preorder was placed in late June of 2014). If you're deadset on getting one your best bet would be to monitor eBay or the Amazon Marketplace for scalpers relisting them, but be prepared to pay a significant markup.

Rarely, and I do mean rarely, brick and mortar stores will get shipments of the collector's editions of games you can find. I would not count on this, but it's a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

According to Gamestop, the Collector's Editions were sold out around August of last year. I was able to buy one off of Ebay but it was for much more than I expected.